# Font Awesome's JS 5: fill "empty parts" on stacked icons

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Using Font Awesome's JS 5 I would like to create a simple stacked icon with both clock and calendar.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js"></script>

<span class="fa-layers fa-4x">
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 
    <i class="far fa-clock" data-fa-transform="shrink-6 down-6 right-6"></i>
</span>
```

The above snippet is more or less what I expect except that I would like "inside" of the clock to be filled in white color not transparent so I don't see the calendar.

To be more explicit, here is the wished result (some bad photoshoping...)

[image]

Comment: I doubt that you can add new shapes to an icon, which you would need to do in this case. You could use the circle-icon, make it white and place it behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the circle-icon, make it white and place it behind it.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js"></script>

<span class="fa-layers fa-4x">
<i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> 
<i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:white" data-fa-transform="shrink-6 down-6 right-6"></i>
<i class="far fa-clock" data-fa-transform="shrink-6 down-6 right-6"></i>
</span>
```